# JavaScript: I want to omit receiver in callback

Tags: javascript, callback

As the title says, I want to omit receiver in callback.

Example:

```
very_long_name = [1,2,-1,3,4,5,6,7];
very_long_name.some((v,i) => v==-1 ? very_long_name.splice(i,1) : false );
```

↓

```
very_long_name = [1,2,-1,3,4,5,6,7];
very_long_name.some((v,i) => v==-1 ? p.splice(i,1) : false );
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: "receiver" doesn't make sense in that sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [third parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Parameters) of the callback:

```
very_long_name.some((v,i,p) => v==-1 ? p.splice(i,1) : false );
```

From the linked article:

> **array** *(p in your case)*
>   The array some() was called upon.

Comment: Thanks for a rapid answer!!